# Python prime number code running slow

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, primes

I am trying to solve the problem mentioned here: https://www.spoj.pl/problems/PRIME1/

I am also giving the description below.

> Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!
>
> Input
>
> The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
>
> Output
>
> For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.`

My code is as below. I am thinking remove method on list is very slow.

```
import sys
import math

num = int(sys.stdin.readline());
indices = []
maxrange = 2
while(num > 0):
    a,b = sys.stdin.readline().split(" ");
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    if(a < 2):
        a = 2
    indices.append((a,b))
    if(b > maxrange):
        maxrange= b          
    num = num - 1

val = int(math.sqrt(maxrange)+1)
val2 = int(math.sqrt(val)+1)
checks = range(2,val2)

for i in range(2,val2):
    for j in checks:
        if(i!= j and j%i == 0):
            checks.remove(j)

primes = range(2,val)
for i in checks:
    for j in primes:
        if(i != j and j%i == 0):
            primes.remove(j)

primes2 = range(2,maxrange)
for i in primes:
    for j in primes2:
        if(j != i and j%i == 0):
            primes2.remove(j)

for (a,b) in indices:
    for p in primes2:
        if(a<= p and b >= p):
            print p
        if(p > b):
            break
    print
```

I think python list remove is very slow. My code is correct but I am getting timelimit exceeded. can someone help me improve this code.

Comment: Have you [profiled](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) it?

Comment: I haven't done that..let me do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the element that is not a prime, why not replace it with some sentinel value, perhaps `-1` or `None`?  Then when printing, just print the values that aren't sentinels.

Use a list of length `(n-m)`, and then the index for number `i` is `x[m+i]`.

Comment: how to replace it..I don't have index in the list

Comment: My mistake, I looked too quickly at your code.  I believe it's the index method on lists.  However, that would be linear in the length of the list for each lookup, so it may be quite expensive itself... But, knowing what the lower bound is, you could have a list in which `I` is found at `lower_bound + I`, and just use an index lookup

Comment: this is really the way to go, even if you have to change the algorithm so that you _have_ the index.

Answer (score 3):

A primality testing function will perform best. There's pseudocode on the [Miller-Rabin wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)

Comment: Isn't this a probablistic answer? For hundred thousand, I think it will take significant time.

Comment: If you follow the link to the wikipedia page, you'll see that there's a deterministic, efficient variant that works for the range of numbers you're interested in. You don't need to check all 100K numbers, for example you need only consider those that are 1 or 5 modulo 6.

Comment: So your deterministic variant has to test 1/3 as many numbers as the naive 100K check. So the variant needs to be at most 3x the running time of the naive 100K check to be faster. Well, you could optimize the naive 100K check and only do odd numbers after 2. So then the ratio is 1/3N to 1/2N (and if you discount anything ending in 5, when > 5, you'd get to 1/3N to 2/5N - so your speed advantage would dwindle to 20% or so).

Comment: @typo Are you sure you've read the question? It's to generate primes between a given m and n, not to generate all primes below 100K.

Comment: Yes, I've read the question. You're given two numbers ( m <= n <= 1000000000)  whose difference may be at most 100,000. So, worst case, there are 100,000 numbers to check using the naive method.

Answer (score 1):

remove() isn't slow in the grand scheme of things, it's just that the code calls it a LOT.

As dappawit suggests, rather than modifying the list, change the value in the list so you know that it isn't a valid number to use.

I also see that when you generate the set of prime numbers, you use `range(2,maxrange)` which is okay, but not efficient if the lower bound is much greater than 2. You'll be wasting computing time on generating primes that aren't even relevant to the problem space. If nothing else, keep track of minrange as well as maxrange.

A bug with your original code is that you use `range(2,maxrange)`. That means `maxrange` is not in the list of numbers considered. Try `3 5` as input for a and b to see the bug.

`range(2,maxrange+1)` fixes the problem.

Another bug in the code is that you modify the original sequence:

From [Python docs - for-statement](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

> It is not safe to modify the sequence being iterated over in the loop (this can only happen for mutable sequence types, such as lists). If you need to modify the list you are iterating over (for example, to duplicate selected items) you must iterate over a copy. The slice notation makes this particularly convenient:

My python skills are rudimentary, but this seems to work:

Old:

```
primes2 = range(2,maxrange)
for i in primes:
     for j in primes2:
         if(j != i and j%i == 0):
             primes2.remove(j)

for (a,b) in indices:
    for p in primes2:
        if(a<= p and b >= p):
```

New:

```
primes2 = array.array('L', range(minrange,maxrange+1))
for i in primes:
    for j in primes2:
        if(j != i and j%i == 0):
            primes2[j-minrange] = 0

for (a,b) in indices:
    for p in primes2:
        if (p != 0):
            if(a<= p and b >= p):
```

You could also skip generating the set of prime numbers and just test the numbers directly, which would work if the sets of numbers you have to generate prime numbers are not overlapping (no work duplication).
[enter link description here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a deterministic variant of the [Miller–Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants_of_the_test) for small odd integers in Python:

```
from math import log

def isprime(n):
    assert 1 < n < 4759123141 and n % 2 != 0, n

    # (n-1) == 2**s * d
    s = 0
    d = n-1
    while d & 1 == 0:
        s += 1
        d >>= 1
    assert d % 2 != 0 and (n-1) == d*2**s

    for a in [2, 7, 61]:
        if not 2 <= a <= min(n-1, int(2*log(n)**2)):
            break
        if (pow(a, d, n) != 1 and
            all(pow(a, d*2**r, n) != (n-1) for r in xrange(s))):
            return False
    return True
```

The code intent is to be an executable pseudo-code.